# Jquery append value to Django choicefield

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a form which looks like this:

```
    CROP_CHOICES = (
      ('', 'Choose..'),
    )
     class CropMonitoringPlantHeightForm(forms.Form):
      Crop = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CROP_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select(attrs = {
        'readonly': 'True',
        'class': 'form-control seleckpicker'
      }))
     plot = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Plot.objects.all(), widget = Select(attrs = {
      'disabled': 'True',
      'class': 'form-control seleckpicker'
    }), empty_label = "Choose Plot")
```

So what I want is when a user on "template.html" select plot, then crop names related to that plot appended to Crop choice field;

Hence i did this:

```
var options = '<option value="">Choose crop..</option>';
crops = plotmanagement_info[1];
for (var i = 0; i < crops.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + crops[i] + '">' + crops[i] + '</option>';
}
$("#id_Crop").html(options);
$("#id_Crop option:selected").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Values are appended to crop choice field;

Problem:
When i try to submit my form i get this error message:

Select a valid choice. XXX is not one of the available choices.

How can append value to Django choicefield using query...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that on the Django side the `choices` are populated without the choice that you added and when it validates, it sees that your selection isn't one of them. I think you can override this somewhere (i.e. in the specific field's clean method) so that you either add that choice to the list or do not validate if it's in the list previously specified.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#field-choices) says that:


"Note that choices can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn’t change much, if ever."

Comment: How can i do that @ makavel? how can i append choices using jquery on django template

Comment: You can't do that in jQuery, but you may be able to do that after posting the data in the form on the view level.

Comment: Well; i was able to fix the problem, by changing the choicefield into modelchoicefield...therefore:Crop =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Crop.objects.all(),widget=Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control seleckpicker'}),empty_label="Choose Crop..")

Answer (score 0):

Your CROP_CHOICES is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples%22tuple%22), which is inmutable.

Try to use a list instead:

```
CROP_CHOICES = [
    ('', 'Choose..'),
]
```